# Dialog Fragment Not Displaying on Launch

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-dialogfragment

So I have some application, on startup it launches a splash screen activity and checks to see if a user account has been linked to the app. If one has the app launches the main activity and bypasses the splash silently. If there is no user account it pulls down a database in a `AsyncTask` and asks the user to Login/Create an Account.

On first startup the app syncs with a server and pulls down a database. I'm trying to get a `DialogFragment` with an indeterminate progress bar to display as this database is pulled down. Right now the `DialogFragment` is created in the `onPreExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`, the `AsyncTask` is executed in the Activity's `onStart()` method the problem I'm having is that the dialog is not being drawn to the screen.

I have debug logging that shows that the dialog's `onCreate()` is executing and the sync is successful. The dialog is shown/dismissed in `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` respectively both of which execute on the UI thread. I realize that if the database download is fast this won't display very long but I'm not seeing even a brief flash of the dialog in the emulator.

Could this be a 'problem' with the emulator where all the dialog's frames are being skipped or am I not creating the dialog at a point where it would actually be drawn to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I see 2 possible reasons:
1. Maybe you doesn't show right the DialogFragment, see [example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).
2. The AsyncTask is launched in a different thread (Not on UIThread), so if you need to access the UIThread (from the AsuncTask), try to override `onProgressUpdate` see [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).
Hope it was helpfull.